# Get first not null value spark scala on a dataframe during aggregation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

During the aggregation group by, currently I am taking the first value. But I need the first not null value for the visit_id column. Please let me know if there is any approach in Spark Scala.

```
DF.groupBy("id").agg(lit(first(col("visit_id"))).alias("visit_id")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can `filter` before grouping it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ignoreNulls` parameter in `first`:

*Example*:

```
val df = Seq((1, Some(2)), (1, None), (2, None), (2, Some(3))).toDF("id", "visit_id")

df.show
+---+--------+
| id|visit_id|
+---+--------+
|  1|       2|
|  1|    null|
|  2|    null|
|  2|       3|
+---+--------+

df.groupBy("id").agg(first("visit_id", ignoreNulls=true).as("visit_id")).show
+---+--------+
| id|visit_id|
+---+--------+
|  1|       2|
|  2|       3|
+---+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you , I will try that