# adding a record to the head so that it is not duplicated using scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following dataframe:
PK's -> code_id, date

- no duplicates have to be generated, however, there are

```
+-------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+----------+
|code_id|date      |import1|import2|import3|postal_code|country   |
+-------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+----------+
|9900   |2024-02-21|50.0   |null   |null   |28032      |california|
|9900   |2024-02-21|null   |null   |7.0    |28032      |california|
|9900   |2024-02-21|null   |100.0  |null   |28032      |california|
|5000   |2024-02-21|230.0  |null   |null   |28032      |california|
|5000   |2024-02-21|null   |46.4   |null   |28032      |california|
|5000   |2024-02-21|null   |null   |180.2  |28032      |california|
+-------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+----------+
```

I want to group it by ("code_id", "date") and the result I hope should be:

```
+-------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+----------+
|code_id|date      |import1|import2|import3|postal_code|country   |
+-------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+----------+
|9900   |2024-02-21|50.0   |100.0  |7.0    |28032      |california|
|5000   |2024-02-21|230.0  |46.4   |180.2  |28032      |california|
+-------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+----------+
```

Would this be possible?
I've tried making a groupBy but I'm not liking the way it's turning out.
 `data.groupBy("code_id", "date").agg(collect_set(struct("import1","import2","import3","postal_code","country")))`

thanksss!

Comment: You need to show the actual code you tried using, and explain the actual reason for your "not liking" the result (as well as the result itself).

Comment: @Dima i have usde this ``` data.groupBy("code_id", "date").agg(collect_set(struct("import1","import2","import3","postal_code","country")))```

Comment: you can also try converting it to a dataset with the help of a case class and then use `groupByKey(data => (data.country_code, data.date)).flatMapGroups {//iterate the group with preferred logic and populate fields.}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution would be to use `groupBy` to aggregate a `collect_list` on each of those "import?" columns (then pick the first element via [`element_at`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#max_by(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,ord:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) from each list) and take the `first` for each of the rest of the columns.

```
val data = Seq(
  (9900, "2024-02-21", Some(50.0), None, None, "28032", "california"),
  (9900, "2024-02-21", None, None, Some(7.0), "28032", "california"),
  (9900, "2024-02-21", None, Some(100.0), None, "28032", "california"),
  (5000, "2024-02-21", Some(230.0), None, None, "28032", "california"),
  (5000, "2024-02-21", None, Some(46.4), None, "28032", "california"),
  (5000, "2024-02-21", None, None, Some(180.2), "28032", "california") 
).toDF("code_id", "date", "import1", "import2", "import3", "postal_code", "country")

val keys = Seq("code_id", "date")
val imports = data.columns.filter(_.matches("import\\d+"))
val rest = data.columns diff keys diff imports

val aggCols = imports.map(c => element_at(collect_list(col(c)), 1).as(c))
val restCols = rest.map(c => first(col(c)).as(c))

data.
  groupBy(keys.map(col): _*).agg(aggCols.head, aggCols.tail ++ restCols: _*).
  show

// +-------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+----------+
// |code_id|      date|import1|import2|import3|postal_code|   country|
// +-------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+----------+
// |   9900|2024-02-21|   50.0|  100.0|    7.0|      28032|california|
// |   5000|2024-02-21|  230.0|   46.4|  180.2|      28032|california|
// +-------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+----------+
```

Alternatively, applying `first` (ignoreNulls=true) over `Window` partitioning with `rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)` to individual "import?" columns would work as well, although an additional `groupBy` would still be needed given the required output.

Comment: I think this is a good option, but I would like to ask you a question.
if the fields are not called import1,import2,import3 but have a different name: "gf_amount", "gf_import", "gf_percent".

applying your solution, this line is giving me problems: 
`val imports = data.columns.filter(_.matches("gf_\d+"))`
I understand that if I put the "gf" it would catch the rest of the fields but the error message is the following: `"next on empty iterator"`. thankss for your support

Comment: I have solved it by adding it as a list! thanks!

Comment: @Jersson GA, you could just change the filter to `data.columns.filter(_.startsWith("gf_"))`.

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution can be found in the below link.

[Get First non-null value in a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54793177/get-first-not-null-value-spark-scala-on-a-dataframe-during-aggregation)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore nulls in the aggregate. See the following example:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import first

data = [
    (9900, "2024-02-21", 50.0, None, None, 28032, "california"),
    (9900, "2024-02-21", None, None, 7.0, 28032, "california"),
    (9900, "2024-02-21", None, 100.0, None, 28032, "california"),
    (5000, "2024-02-21", 230.0, None, None, 28032, "california"),
    (5000, "2024-02-21", None, 46.4, None, 28032, "california"),
    (5000, "2024-02-21", None, None, 180.2, 28032, "california")
]

columns = ["code_id", "date", "import1", "import2", "import3", "postal_code", "country"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

result_df = df.groupBy("code_id", "date") \
    .agg(
        first("import1", ignorenulls=True).alias("import1"),
        first("import2", ignorenulls=True).alias("import2"),
        first("import3", ignorenulls=True).alias("import3"),
        first("postal_code").alias("postal_code"),
        first("country").alias("country")
    )

result_df.show()

Output:
+-------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+----------+
|code_id|      date|import1|import2|import3|postal_code|   country|
+-------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+----------+
|   5000|2024-02-21|  230.0|   46.4|  180.2|      28032|california|
|   9900|2024-02-21|   50.0|  100.0|    7.0|      28032|california|
+-------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+----------+
```